# Rounding error from array -> string -> array conversion

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, rounding-error

I am trying to create an array by horizontally concatenating data in 4 columns, like so:

```
col1=numpy.arange(191.25,196.275,.001)[:, numpy.newaxis]
nrows=col1.shape[0]

col2=numpy.zeros((nrows,1),dtype=numpy.int)
col3=numpy.zeros((nrows,1),dtype=numpy.int)
col4=numpy.ones((nrows,1),dtype=numpy.int)

a=numpy.hstack((col1,col2,col3,col4))
```

Then I convert it to a string:

```
a_str = '\n'.join('\t'.join('%0.3f' %x for x in y) for y in a)+'\n'
```

And convert it back to a 2d numpy array:

```
a2=numpy.array(filter(None,re.split('[\n\t]+',a_str)),dtype=float).reshape(-1,4)
```

But now when I get FALSE, when I compare:

```
a[-1,0]==a2[-1,0]
```

When I look at the individual values, I see:

```
a[-1,0]=196.27500000002399
a2[-1,0]=196.27500000000001
```

Is there some floating point/rounding error associated with converting from array to string and back (a2 is actually closer to the desired value of 196.275 than a)?  How do I make it so that the values are equal?  My suspicion is that when I produce the error by initially generating col1 by iterative addition that compounds the errors in the later array indices.  Does this mean I should instead explicitly enumerate the values of col1 instead, or is there a work around?

Comment: If you need your numpy arrays to roundtrip, use `numpy.save`. Don't manually convert them to strings yourself.

Comment: I have to convert them to strings for communication with lab equipment I'm using because the API only recognizes strings.  I want to be able to write to the equipment, then read back from the equipment and compare the two to make sure it received the data correctly.

Comment: But in that case, why do you need to convert the response from the equipment back into a number? If you just want to check that the input and output are equal, shouldn't you just compare them as strings?

Comment: The problem is, I have to clean up the data a little before I compare it.  I know I need to round to the nearest 3rd decimal place for at least the first column (not sure yet about the other columns).

Comment: Ah, so the equipment basically adds a bit of "noise" to the output. In that case, what you want is to do an equality check _with tolerance_. In numpy, that's [`numpy.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), with your `rtol` and `atol` parameters chosen appropriately. I don't know why `numpy.all` was working for you (per your answer), but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There fundamentally isn't really a solution to this. Generally speaking, a finite decimal string and a finite binary representation have no exact equivalents. Rounding errors will be accrued in such conversions, and rather than testing for exact equivalency, constructs like np.allclose will have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for my situation, and that is to basically use a2 instead of a.  Then when I convert a2 to a string and back to an array (say, a3) by the same process as in the question, I can get True for `numpy.all(a2==a3)`.  Unlike a, all values of a2 and a3 appear to be within the desired value by +/- 1e-14 and identical to each other.